# Got edit error onmodified field Purchtable createorder x++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Every time Im using this code I get a error "you cannot edit the record in the table Purchtable".
I cant proceed the order with it. My task is to get the default address for each site.

```
[ExtensionOf(formdatasourcestr(PurchCreateOrder, PurchTable))]
final class PurchCreateOrderGetDefAdress_Extension
{
[FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(PurchCreateOrder, PurchTable, OrderAccount), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified)]
public static void OrderAccount_OnModified(FormDataObject sender, FormDataFieldEventArgs e)
{
    Formdatasource                              purchtable_ds = sender.datasource();
    PurchTable                                  purchtable = purchtable_ds.cursor();
    InventSite                                  inv;
    InventLocation                              invent;

    str iid =  UserInfoSz::findDefaultSite(curUserId()).InventSiteId;
    purchtable.inventsiteid = iid;
    purchTable.setAddressFromInventSiteId(iid);

    select firstonly invent where invent.inventsiteid == iid && invent.WMSLocationIdDefaultReceipt == "recv";
    if(invent.RecId !=0)
    {
        purchtable.inventlocationid = invent.InventLocationId;
    }
    else
    {
        select firstonly invent where invent.inventsiteid == iid;
        purchtable.inventlocationid = invent.InventLocationId;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Probably a conflict with the logic in form `PurchCreateOrder`, method `orderAccountModified`. Try extending that method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method `purchTable.setAddressFromInventSiteId(iid);` causes you that problem.

***Try this code:***

```
[ExtensionOf(formdatasourcestr(PurchCreateOrder, PurchTable))]
final class PurchCreateOrderGetDefAdress_Extension
{
    [FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(PurchCreateOrder, PurchTable, OrderAccount), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified)]
    public static void OrderAccount_OnModified(FormDataObject sender, FormDataFieldEventArgs e)
    {
        Formdatasource                              purchtable_ds = sender.datasource();
        PurchTable                                  purchtable = purchtable_ds.cursor();
        InventSite                                  inv;
        InventLocation                              invent;

        str iid =  UserInfoSz::findDefaultSite(curUserId()).InventSiteId;
        ttsbegin;
        If(purchtable.recid)
        {
            purchtable.selectforupdate(true);    
            purchtable.inventsiteid = iid;
            purchTable.setAddressFromInventSiteId(iid);

            select firstonly invent where invent.inventsiteid == iid && invent.WMSLocationIdDefaultReceipt == "recv";
            if(invent.RecId !=0)
            {
                purchtable.inventlocationid = invent.InventLocationId;
            }
            else
            {
                select firstonly invent where invent.inventsiteid == iid;
                purchtable.inventlocationid = invent.InventLocationId;
            }
        }
        ttscommit;
    }
}
```

Comment: No still not good. I tried to debug it and it looks like there is no recid for purchtable. {recid = 0}

Comment: Update the post, now you will not have the error. Anyway try to find why purchtable it's empty to make it work correctly

Comment: It works fine now. Thank you. There was a problem from older solutions. Could you help me with one more thing ? I want to catch if purchTable.setAddressFromInventSiteId(iid); isset correcly because if I dont have a address connected to inventsite it lets the default site address on form from companyinfo I quess.

Comment: Okay. I got used what I needed from this method. Now its good